# How can I print X quantity of strings in Y amount of time?

Tags: python, loops, math, time, iterator

Is really bothering me to try figure this out. I can explain myself:
I need for example, to print 5 strings per second, so in 1 second I need to print those 5 strings, and the next second another 5.
How can I divide the amount of time a loop (as I think it should be) runs in a second, so I can print the 5 strings in that time, and printed in equaly amount of time?

```
["text1", "text2", "text3", "text4", "text5"]
```

each one printed in 200ms?

how can I control in a loop the time of each iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import time

start=time.time()    
for k in tablestrings:
    print k
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

will work fine, but might give you some problems if you're looking for high precision

```
import time

start=time.time()    
for k in range(len(tablestrings)):
    release=False
    while not release:
        if time.time()>start+0.2*k:
            release=True
    print tablestrings[k]
```

should derive less from the 1 print every 0.2 seconds rule

Comment: I'll try and let you know

Comment: Your code now works well in the Python console. It works less will in an IPython console, probably due to buffering. To work there you should add a line to flush the output buffer `sys.stdout.flush()` just after the print statement. That does improve the printing but is not yet perfect.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I just iterate on k integer and I call tablestrings[k]. Your suggestion was more elegant but since it seems to be a bit less universal I stick to my ugly habits.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
import time

texts = ["text1", "text2", "text3", "text4", "text5"]

for text in texts:
  print(text)
  time.sleep(0.2)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html for Python 2.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html for Python 3.